# Passing a reactiveEvent to update plot regression in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have the following App:

[image]

The objective is to:

- 1. Add new points to the plot when the user clicks on it.
- 2. These are updated in the table (where you can remove points also)
- 3. (Where the App fails): Plot the linear regression and spline regression based on the new users updated data.

When I comment-out the lines

```
  #geom_line(aes(x=x, y=fitlm(), color="Simple")) +
  #geom_line(aes(x=x, y=fitbslm(), color="B-spline")) +
```

in the `ggplot` `renderPlot()` function at the end, I am able to add points and update the plot without problem

The problem occurs when I try to add these two lines back into the plot and then the updated data is passed to the `fitlm` and `fitBslm` `eventReactive()` functions.

For some reason it doesn't want to re-compute the regressions and apply/update the plot.

Question:

How can I introduce the regressions to the ggplot based on the new users updated data. (I am happy with it updating automatically or through a button)

After clicking the `Generate Plot` button it makes the below plot. However, the plot failed `Error: [object Object]` when I click on the plot to add a new point.

App:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(splines2)
library(ggplot2)


# Get the Temp values, which defines the accepted range of knots
# for the b-spline model.
library(dplyr)
data("airquality")
airquality <- filter(airquality, !is.na(Ozone)) %>% 
  select(c(Ozone, Temp)) %>% 
  set_names(c("x", "y"))
uniqueTemps <- unique(airquality[order(airquality$x), "x"])
selectedTemps <- sample(uniqueTemps, 2)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Simple Linear vs Spline Fit"),
  
  # Sidebar
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("knotSel", "Select knot values for B-spline fit:",
                  uniqueTemps, selected=selectedTemps,
                  multiple=TRUE),
      actionButton("calcFit", "Generate Plot"),
      actionButton("computeRegressions", "Compute Regressions")
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot_splines", click = "plot_click"),
      h4("Example Data: airquality {datasets}"),
      p("This plot uses linear models to predict ozone levels based on temperature readings.",
        tags$br(),
        tags$em("Simple formula: ")
        # tags$code("lm(Ozone ~ Temp + I(Temp^2) + I(Temp^3) - 1, airquality)"),
        # tags$br(),
        # tags$em("Spline formula: "),
        # tags$code("lm(airquality$Ozone ~ bSpline(airquality$Temp, knots=getKnots(), degree=3) - 1)")
      ),
      fluidRow(column(width = 6,
                      h4("Click plot to add points"),
                      actionButton("rem_point", "Remove Last Point")
                      #plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click")
                      ),
               column(width = 6,
                      h4("Table of points on plot"),
                      tableOutput("table"))),
      fluidRow(column(width = 6,
                      DTOutput('tab1')),
               column(width = 6,
                      DTOutput('tab2'))
               )
    )
  )))

server <- (function(input, output) {
  
  # Load the airquality dataset.
  # data("airquality")
  # # Remove observations lacking an Ozone measure.
  # airquality <- filter(airquality, !is.na(Ozone)) %>% 
  #   select(c(Ozone, Temp)) %>% 
  #   set_names(c("y", "x"))

  
  ########################### Add selections to plot ###########################
  ## 1. set up reactive dataframe ##
  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$DT <- data.frame(x = numeric(),
                          y = numeric()
  ) %>% 
    bind_rows(airquality)
  
  
  
  ## 2. Create a plot ##
  # output$plot1 = renderPlot({
  #   ggplot(values$DT, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  #     geom_point(size = 5) +
  #     lims(x = c(0, 100), y = c(0, 100)) +
  #     theme(legend.position = "bottom")
  #   # include so that colors don't change as more color/shape chosen
  #   # scale_color_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  #   # scale_shape_discrete(drop = FALSE)
  # })
  
  ## 3. add new row to reactive dataframe upon clicking plot ##
  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
    # each input is a factor so levels are consistent for plotting characteristics
    add_row <- data.frame(x = input$plot_click$x,
                          y = input$plot_click$y
    )
    # add row to the data.frame
    values$DT <- rbind(values$DT, add_row)
  })
  
  ## 4. remove row on actionButton click ##
  observeEvent(input$rem_point, {
    rem_row <- values$DT[-nrow(values$DT), ]
    values$DT <- rem_row
  })
  
  ## 5. render a table of the growing dataframe ##
  output$table <- renderTable({
    values$DT
  })
  ##############################################################################
  # Fit the simple linear model
  fitlm <- eventReactive(input$calcFit, {
    slm <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3) - 1, values$DT)
    fitlm <- slm$fitted.values
    fitlm
  })
  
  # Get knot selection
  getKnots <- reactive({as.integer(input$knotSel)})
  
  # Fit the spline model, with the knot selection
  fitBslm <- eventReactive(input$calcFit, {
    bsMat <- bSpline(values$DT$x, knots=getKnots(), degree=3)
    bslm <- lm(values$DT$y ~ bsMat - 1)
    bslm
  })
  
  # observeEvent({
  #   print(fitBslm())
  # })
  
  # Generate the plot
  output$plot_splines <- renderPlot({
    splineMdl <- fitBslm()
    fitbslm <- splineMdl$fitted.values
    
    cols <- c("Simple"="#ef615c", "B-spline"="#20b2aa", "knot"="black")
    g <- ggplot(values$DT, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
      geom_point(color="blue") +
     geom_line(aes(x=x, y=fitlm(), color="Simple")) +
      #geom_line(aes(x=x, y=fitbslm(), color="B-spline")) +
      geom_vline(aes(color="knot"), xintercept=getKnots(), linetype="dashed", size=1) +
      scale_colour_manual(name="Fit Lines",values=cols) +
      ggtitle("Ozone as predicted by Temp", "(knots shown as vertical lines)")
    g
  })
  
  output$tab1 <- renderDataTable(
    airquality
  )
  
  output$tab2 <- renderDataTable(
    values$DT
  )
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `eventReactive` to just `reactive`.  Also, you just need `fitbslm` in the second `geom_line` without `()`.  Try this

```
server <- (function(input, output) {

  ########################### Add selections to plot ###########################
  ## 1. set up reactive dataframe ##
  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$DT <- data.frame(x = numeric(),
                          y = numeric()
  ) %>% 
    bind_rows(airquality)
 
  ## 3. add new row to reactive dataframe upon clicking plot ##
  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
    # each input is a factor so levels are consistent for plotting characteristics
    add_row <- data.frame(x = input$plot_click$x,
                          y = input$plot_click$y
    )
    # add row to the data.frame
    values$DT <- rbind(values$DT, add_row)
  })
  
  ## 4. remove row on actionButton click ##
  observeEvent(input$rem_point, {
    rem_row <- values$DT[-nrow(values$DT), ]
    values$DT <- rem_row
  })
  
  ## 5. render a table of the growing dataframe ##
  output$table <- renderTable({
    values$DT
  })
  ##############################################################################
  # Fit the simple linear model
  # fitlm <- eventReactive(input$calcFit, {
  fitlm <- reactive({
    slm <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3) - 1, values$DT)
    fitlm <- slm$fitted.values
    fitlm
  })
  
  # Get knot selection
  getKnots <- reactive({as.integer(input$knotSel)})
  
  # Fit the spline model, with the knot selection
  #fitBslm <- eventReactive(input$calcFit, {
  fitBslm <- reactive({
    bsMat <- bSpline(values$DT$x, knots=getKnots(), degree=3)
    bslm <- lm(values$DT$y ~ bsMat - 1)
    bslm
  })
 
  
  myPlot <- reactive({
    splineMdl <- fitBslm()
    fitbslm <- splineMdl$fitted.values
    cols <- c("Simple"="#ef615c", "B-spline"="#20b2aa", "knot"="black")
    
    g <- ggplot(values$DT, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
      geom_point(color="blue") +
      geom_line(aes(x=x, y=fitlm(), color="Simple")) +
      geom_line(aes(x=x, y=fitbslm , color="B-spline")) +
      geom_vline(aes(color="knot"), xintercept=getKnots(), linetype="dashed", size=1) +
      scale_colour_manual(name="Fit Lines",values=cols) +
      ggtitle("Ozone as predicted by Temp", "(knots shown as vertical lines)")
    g
  })
  
  # Generate the plot
  output$plot_splines <- renderPlot({
    myPlot()
  })
  
  output$tab1 <- renderDataTable(
    airquality
  )
  
  output$tab2 <- renderDataTable(
    values$DT
  )
  
})
```